# Could a group of musicians play a new piece by sight-reading on first attempt?

Tags: sight-reading, orchestra

Is it possible, without any rehearsal, relying solely on sight-reading?
Are there any experiments of this kind with octets, nonets, maytbe entire orchestras?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. High-paid studio musicians are all expected to [sight read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sight_reading#Professional_use) perfectly on the first read. There are even [programs](https://www.disneyyouth.com/programs/performing-arts/workshops,instrumental/) to illustrate and develop the skill for younger musicians. Many movie soundtracks are recordings of first-time sight reading.

Comment: It's cheaper also. You don't have to pay musicians as much for time.

Comment: However hourly rate can be around the $1000/hr mark, so cheaper is relative.

Comment: Possible, but in reality how many composers and conductors are happy with the first read? It takes a number of rehearsals to get the nuances perfect. In movies, you may have other considerations that have to work with other sound elements (Foley, dialogue). A first read by competent musicians is certainly possible, but getting what the composer or director or conductor wants in a first read is rare.

Comment: Anecdote I was told by my band director: over half of the recordings for the Star Wars Ep. 1 soundtrack were first reads. I think these musicians are some of the world's best, and can actually perform at that level.

Comment: Anecdote: Listen to Frank Sinatra's recording of "One For My Baby (And One More For The Road)". He sings it once through, but it's written with a first ending back to the beginning, with the pickup note and the word "it's" ("It's quarter to three...") The song ends "the road, that long, long road." Frankie sings "the road, that long, long, it's long." Was he seeing the music for the very first time as he sang it for the recording? Yes, musicians can play or sing it on sight, no rehearsal, one take, and get a hit record.

Comment: Sinatra must have liked "that long, long, it's long" because he did it in live performances too. I can't say whether he DID sight-read the first recording, but he had the ability. And it's not unprofessional to do that. In fact it's VERY professional to do it when necessary.

Comment: Singers are another business--I doubt Sinatra was reading from music at all in making that recording. It's a standard tune, so he probably reviewed the arrangement they had written for the orchestra with his producer beforehand and took many liberties with the actual line and words. That's what makes different singers distinctive.

Comment: i think there might be some confusion between a first *read* and a first *take*. great performances can be got from a first read but the likelihood of a (film) score being recording on a first read is zero. music is usually received ahead of time (not always) and then rehearsed before it's recorded.

Comment: Second link is dead

Answer (score 2):

I doubt, a full symphonic orchestra will achieve a breath-taking recording on the first attempt. Of course anybody knows its Beethoven, so it is not exactly sight-reading, but these points make it difficult:

- the conductors individual interpretation
- increased complexity of voice interaction
- sheer area of a late-romantic orchestra make it challenge to hear
  soloists from remote groups

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  And all too often they have to.  Meticulous scoring, music preparation and playing skills are taken for granted in the professional music world.  But it's also great to hear a performance that has benefited from sufficient rehearsal and a few previous outings.